# jQuery DataTables Column filtering for dropdown rendered column data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

In my table I am creating a dropdown filter in the footer with this:

```
            initComplete : function(settings, json){
            this.api().columns([1,2,4,5,7,9,10,11,12,13,15,17,18,19]).every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );
                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );
                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
```

In several of the columns I am creating a dropdown based on a list of values that comes in the model and the selected value from the particular row:

```
                {
                "render": function(data, type, full, meta){
                    var $select = $("<select></select>", { 'class' : 'ctrl-status'});
                    $select.attr("id", "ddl" + full[0])
                    $.each(statuslist, function (Value, Text) {
                        var $opt = $('<option value=' + Text.Value + '>' + Text.Text + '</option>');

                        if (Text.Value === full[6]){
                            $opt.attr("selected", "selected");
                        }
                        $select.append($opt);
                    });
                    return $select.prop("outerHTML");
                }
            },
```

The problem is that the filter dropdown shows the values correctly but when I select one of the values nothing is selected or displayed.  In each row I am including the selected value in a column and hiding that column.  In other words, for status, there are multiple values that are rendered for the dropdown, but the next column for that row contains the selected status of the project. and I set the dropdown to that value.  Is there a way to, based upon the column I am filtering to look at the next column for that filtering values?

Comment: did you double check that your "on change" in your drop down filter is actually firing when you select something?

Comment: @AndrewLohr yes, and it does indeed fire.  Problem is that it is a rendered dropdown and it the filter does not see any matching values.